# Get IP address of the server that is hosting a client-side js application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, nginx, asp.net-web-api

There is a `back-end` server using `asp.net core web-api`, and the `Nginx` as `reverse-proxy`, all hosted on `docker` on the ubuntu server.

Also, a `client-side` web application (`reactjs`) which makes REST API calls to the back-end using `JS 'Fetch'` (or Axios, etc...)

The `client-side` app is not centralized and it could be hosted on any number of servers.
*(Let's say hosted on 5 servers.

So now we have 1 back-end server, and 5 servers hosting that reactjs app.)*

### objective

Every time one of the client apps makes an HTTP request to the back-end, I want to get the IP address of the ***server*** that's hosting that specific reactjs app.
But what I'm getting is the end-user IP address, not the server that's hosting the react app

Is it possible to do that? without asking the users to put their server's IP into their REST requests manually?

I've tried some Nginx configurations with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The server would have to pass its identity to the front-end application in some form, and the front-end application would have to include this in the back-end call.  The initial server isn't involved in the call from the browser application to the back-end so this needs to be included in some other channel.